# Random Spanning Tree Edge Probability

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on a problem with a Loop Erased Random Walk used to create random spanning trees from a graph. The problem has many parts, but there are two hints to help with the more complicated problems. The hints are essentially:

1.Figure out the probability that any given edge will be contained in the uniform spanning tree.

2.Figure out the probability that an edge is added in a given direction (given the below algorithm) in the uniform spanning tree.

I have been working through this for hours and hours now and have hit a wall. Any tips towards figuring these out would be extremely helpful as I have no idea where to begin at this point.

**Random Walk Algorithm:**

Pick an arbitrary root in V.
Begin at root and traverse graph randomly.
Whenever we reach a vertex that has not yet been added to the tree, we add the edge that we used to reach that vertex to our spanning tree

Comment: My intuition is that the probability that any given edge $(u,v)$ will be contained in the uniform spanning tree is 1/#(path(u,v)). But I have no idea how to prove it sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I found this [document, section 1.6](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shayan/courses/approx/adv-approx-1.pdf) useful. It uses the [Kirchoff's matrix tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem).

Denote:

- $\mu$ is the uniform distribution,
- $L_G$ as the Laplacian matrix if $G$ and $\tilde{L}_G$ be the Lapacian with one row and column removed
- $G \text{\\} \{e\}$ be the new graph of $G$ after edge $e$ is contracted.

the answer to question 1 is essentially:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Pr}_{T \sim \mu}(e \in T) &= \frac{\text{number of spanning trees containing } e}{\text{number of spanning trees}} \\
&=\frac{\det(\tilde{L}_{G} \text{\\} \{e\})}{\det(\tilde{L}_{G})}
\end{align*}
$$